# PhpStorm/WebStorm REST client: easy way to send JSON?

Tags: json, rest, phpstorm, webstorm

In 2017 versions of PhpStorm / WebStorm there is a REST client we can use to send requests and analyze responses.

By default, when I send a POST and use the easy form in the UI to create request params, the parameters are formatted as `x-www-form-urlencoded`

[image]

```
instrument=JPY&id=6
```

I want to send data as JSON. So I thought if I add the `content-type: application/json` header, the IDE would format the request params accordingly, but it doesn't.

Currently the only way I see to send stuff in JSON format is to craft the JSON myself and put it in the Request Body as Text section of the IDE

[image]

Am I missing an easy way to send JSON?

Comment: Alternatively, you could use [HTTP client in PhpStorm code editor](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/http-client-in-product-code-editor.html) announced in [the blog](https://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2017/09/editor-based-rest-client/) at year 2017.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not missing it, it's not there yet. Please vote: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-17342